# Omni Channel - Case is Not Routing to Queue

Tags: omnichannel

1. I have created only ONE QUEUE for Omni Channel - Even assigned myself to the Assigned queue users - Cases are not coming to the Queue when the Case Owner is changed from 'User A' to the Queue
2. Tried configuring "Accept Cases Automatically" even then I am unable to receive cases in my Omni Channel Case Queue

What could be the issue.

Comment: What are your routing configurations? Is the queue added to the routing configuration?

Comment: Routing Priority : 1, Routing Model: Most Available, Push-Out Seconds 30 secs, Units of capacity = 4, Queue is added to the routing configuration